# Android Download Manager. status is always pending

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I try to use [Download Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) to download some files form specific URL,
but the download request was never completed.

So I log some information to see what went wrong, it turns out the request is always in pending status, and the `COLUMN_REASON` is `0` which I couldn't find the corresponding description on the document.

```
COLUMN_STATUS: 1
COLUMN_REASON: 0
COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES: -1
COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR: 0
```

Here is how to start a download.

```
val req = DownloadManager.Request(uri).apply {
    addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie)
    allowScanningByMediaScanner()
    setTitle(fullname)
    setDescription(/* description text */)
    setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fullname)
}
val downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(req)
```

And log information for debugging.

```
        val filterQuery = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)
        val cursor = downloadManager.query(filterQuery)
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES))
            val current = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR))
            val status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))
            val reason = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON))

            Log.d("App", "status: " + status.toString())
            Log.d("App", "reason: " + reason.toString())
            Log.d("App", "total: " + total.toString())
            Log.d("App", "current: " +  current.toString())
        }
```

So what's a possible reason that status of request was always pending and how do I debug it?

Any help is going to be appreciated.

Comment: After you enqueue your download, add a sleep and check the status. Is it still pending?

Comment: @BilalNaeem Yes, actually I have added an infinite loop to read and print that information after I enqueue request, and It is always pending.

Comment: Is the internet available on that device

Comment: @BilalNaeem Yes, it is available, I also checked storage volume and permissions. It's my first time to write an android app, is there any way to know something like what request is being processed right now or is any critical resources unavailable for the moment so requests have to wait for it. I don't have enough debug messages to know where to start to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, settings up a VPN seem to solve this problem. It looks like google services have been blocked in my network and after I set up a system global VPN the issue has gone.

Comment: Is that any other way to solve this problem ? How can access without VPN?

Answer (score 1):

DownloadManager outputs its logs to logcat but not under your application's id, so you'll need to show logs for all apps.  There should clues to the failed download in there.  For example, here are a couple of my failure cases.

```
D/DownloadManager: [1988] Starting
W/DownloadManager: [1988] Stop requested with status 500: Internal Server Error
D/DownloadManager: [1988] Finished with status WAITING_TO_RETRY
```

and

```
W/DownloadManager: [1988] Stop requested with status 403: Unhandled HTTP response: 403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait(delay) before checking the status or set the download ID every time in a timer.
enqueue seems to return the download ID too late.
My code works very well:

```
private void startDownload(View v)
{
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://example.com/app/name.apk");
    DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                    |DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
            .setDescription("downloading")
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"name.apk");
    downloadId = mgr.enqueue(req);
 

    getDownloadStatus();
}
```

check status method

```
 private void getDownloadStatus()
    {
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(downloadId);
        Cursor cursor = ((DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE))
                .query(query);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            final Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    query.setFilterById(downloadId);
                    Cursor cursor = ((DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE))
                            .query(query);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int status=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));

                    if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING) {
                        Log.i("DM_STATUS","status is "+" running");
                    }else if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                        Log.i("DM_STATUS","status is "+" success");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }, 100,1);
        }
    }
```