# Android Download Manager Doesn't Work on Private Network

Tags: android, networking, request, vpn, android-download-manager

I use firewall on my network and this network has just one Ip that allowed access. I want to download my apk file from special Ip but Download Manager adds to list as STATUS_PENDING. [How can I download this file without VPN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53869817/android-download-manager-status-is-always-pending)

```
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request downloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlPath));

        downloadRequest.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        downloadRequest.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
        downloadRequest.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        downloadRequest.setTitle("NetworkApp");
        downloadRequest.setDescription("Downloading NetworkApp " + versionName);
        downloadRequest.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, null, "NetworkApp.apk");
        downloadRequest.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);

        long downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(downloadRequest);
```

Android Api:28

Comment: is the vpn connected?

Comment: Vpn is connected but I don't want to use vpn.